# Updating the "How To Ask"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

As part of the ongoing efforts to better our little piece of the vast universe I intend to update the "How To Ask"

This is our current, and default, how to ask blurb:

[image]

Here is one of the custom versions of it. This is from the Hardware Recommendation StackExchange:

[image]

---

For the record, the second box in ours as best I can tell is a Bug. If a Community Manager will allow us to add stuff there I'm all for it, but assume we're only looking at the top box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've reworded Ryan's points a bit.

I've left out the extra header, AFAIK the "How To Ask" can't be changed and having two headers feels a bit redundant to me.

I've left out the last point. I can't think of a way to word it and not sound like a douche, and I don't think this is the right place to take issue with these questions; as I said [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3170/52050), I think we need to come up with some clear guidelines first (it's on my todo list).

So....

> #### How To Ask
>
> - Be specific. Show your work and explain where you’re stuck.
> - Read our guidelines for [**font-identification**](//graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083) and [**style-identification**](//graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2930) questions.
> - For feedback on work, read our [**critique guidelines**](//graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/681).
> - Subjective questions are okay [**if answerable with facts and reason**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).
> - Technical support or questions using graphic-design software for non-design purposes are off-topic and should be asked on [**Super User**](//superuser.com).
>
> For more help, please see [**What topics can I ask about here?**](/help/on-topic) and [**What types of questions should I avoid asking?**](/help/dont-ask)
>
> If your question is about this website, [**ask it on meta**](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: condensed it down (removed the photo since it no longer matched the copy)